# Arrange order of items in collection / outliner?

Tags: collections, outliner

I’d like to manually rearrange my items within a collection but dragging doesn’t do anything ? I’ve turned off Sort Alphabetically but still no joy. Maybe this isn’t possible yet in Blender 2.9 ? I like to keep things organised like in C4D. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid items can't be sorted manually as of this moment. It's a requested feature hopefully coming soon :).

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can't manually rearrange objects like in C4D, you can use an "Empty" which is the equivalent to a "Null Object" to separate objects inside a collection. [image]

Comment: Nice. I'll use the Empty method for now. Fingers crossed for a drag and drop update at some point.